# error when transpose and join table

Tags: sql, database, crosstab

I need to select multiple table and one of it is transposed, my table is listed below:
table_score

```
|ID  | Subject | Score|
----------------------
|001 | 2GSLIG  | 80   |
|001 | 3ECITI  | 70   |
|002 | 2GSLIG  | 75   |
|002 | 3ECITI  | 85   |
-----------------------
```

table_student

```
|ID  | StudentName |
--------------------
|001 | Diana       |
|002 | Yose        |
--------------------
```

then I want to make it into

```
|ID |StudentName| 2GSLIG | 3ECITI |
-----------------------------------
|001| Diana     |  80   |   70   |
|002| Yose      |  85   |   75   |
----------------------------------
```

this is my code so far but I encounter error

```
SELECT (
    ID,
    SUM(IF(Subject = '2GSLIG', Score, 0)) AS `2GSLIG`,
    SUM(IF(Subject = '3ECITI', Score, 0)) AS `3ECITI`
FROM table_score) JOIN (SELECT StudentName from table_student)
GROUP BY ID
```

I wonder if someone would help me, thank you

Comment: What flavor of SQL,  TSQL, PSQL, MySQL, Microsoft, Oracle etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tsc.ID,
       tst.StudentName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tsc.Subject='2GSLIG' THEN tsc.Score END) AS '2GSLIG',
       SUM(CASE WHEN tsc.Subject='3ECITI' THEN tsc.Score END) AS '3ECITI'
FROM table_score tsc
INNER JOIN
table_student tst 
ON tsc.ID = tst.ID
GROUP BY tsc.ID,tst.StudentName;
```

Check this on SQLFIDDLE - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68e96/1

Comment: You can't start column names with a number.  You'd need to enclose with ''.

Answer (score 1):

```
select st.ID,
    st.StudentName,
    SUM(case when sc.Subject = '2GSLIG' then sc.Score end) as `2GSLIG`,
    SUM(case when sc.Subject = '3ECITI' then sc.Score end) as `3ECITI`
from table_score sc
join table_student st on sc.ID = st.ID
group by st.ID,
    st.StudentName
```